# Understanding "requests linking to directory" cmake warning

Tags: cmake

I am compiling an enormous code (100,000+ lines) on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  In the process of doing so, during the cmake (v3.5.1) build process (before running make), I generate a raft of WARNINGS.

E.g.

```
WARNING: Target "gadgetron_moco" requests linking to directory "/usr/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
```

Obviously, I can't repost the code here, but within the source code I found a `moco/CMakeLists.txt`.  Here is a code fragment from that file:

```
if(CUDA_FOUND)
    add_library(gadgetron_moco SHARED
        cpuRegistrationAveragingGadget.h
        gadgetron_moco_export.h
        gpuRegistrationAveragingGadget.h
        gpuRegistrationScatteringGadget.h
        RegistrationAveragingGadget.h
        RegistrationScatteringGadget.h
        ${CPU_GADGETS}
        ${GPU_GADGETS}
      )

    set_target_properties(gadgetron_moco PROPERTIES VERSION ${GADGETRON_VERSION_STRING} SOVERSION ${GADGETRON_SOVERSION})

    target_link_libraries(gadgetron_moco
      gadgetron_gadgetbase
      gadgetron_toolbox_cpucore gadgetron_mricore ${CPU_LIBS} ${GPU_LIBS}
      ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${ISMRMRD_LIBRARIES}
      optimized ${ACE_LIBRARIES} debug ${ACE_DEBUG_LIBRARY}
      )

    install (TARGETS gadgetron_moco DESTINATION lib COMPONENT main)
endif()
```

The command that I used to call cmake:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/gadgetron/ \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++-5 \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc-5 \
    -DBoost_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/ \
    -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/ \
    -DARMADILLO_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/ \
    -DARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/ \
    -DMKLROOT_PATH=/opt/intel/ \
    -DZFP_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/ZFP/inc \
    -DZFP_LIBRARY=/opt/ZFP/lib \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ismrmrd/:/opt/siemens_to_ismrmrd:/usr/lib/ \
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ..
```

Question:
What is the warning exactly telling me?  How do I go about debugging it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### A "library" is a --file--!

The warning is about meaning of the word "library": it is a **file** (`/path/to/xxx.so`, `/path/to/xxx.a` or so), not a *directory*.

Assuming the project is correct, the warning signals about incorrect user-specified settings.

You set a variable `ARMADILLO_LIBRARY`, which is intended to contain a **library**, but you assign `/usr/lib` *directory* to that variable.

Comment: I see.  I was thinking of it like one would with a compiler (like gcc) where you specify the directory to _look_ for the library (i.e. `-L/some/non/standard/path`)

Comment: In CMake "world", a variable suffixed with `_LIBRARY` almost always denotes a *library*. When a variable denotes a library *directory*, it has appropriate suffix: `_DIR`, `_DIRECTORY`, etc.